# Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (Docker / Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, apache2

I just set-up a WordPress development environment with Docker and after restarting Docker I can no longer access the localhost:8000 given I am prompted with

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access this resource.
>
> Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 8000

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: database
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: growthlabs_db
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: wordpress
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      -   ./:/var/www/html
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
volumes:
  wordpress: {}
  db_data: {}
```

Do you know what might be the issue? I did not create a Dockerfile as I was following the tutorial found here https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/.

After the initial docker-compose up everything worked fine. However after I restarted my machine, and Docker of course, I started getting 403 Forbidden.

Could you advise on where did I go wrong?

Comment: Go to `docker-compose.yml` directory and run `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: That is the way I am starting the containers, however once they are up and running I get the "You don't have permission to access this resource." when navigating to localhost:8000

Comment: Do you have any other Apache container running? Run `docker ps` to see

Comment: @Saeed, I avoided doing a docker-compose down since I wrote this post.

I am afraid that if I do I will not be able to start the project again and I will lose my work.

I will come back with feedback on your comment once I stop the containers.

Answer (score 0):

#### You may get similar error when using tild (~) while specifying path to your local directory.

I experienced similar error when specifying local directory path using the syntax:

docker run -p 80:80 -v **~/Desktop**/docker_learn/prj_one/src/:/var/www/html/ test_image

Changing to this solved the problem:

docker run -p 80:80 -v **/home/ahmad/Desktop**/docker_learn/prj_one/src/:/var/www/html/ test_image